# How do I place the Y axis on top of a Bar Chart on Victory Native?

Tags: react-native, victory-charts, victory-native

Here is the code so far:

```
<Chart theme={VictoryTheme.material} width={width} height={height}>
    <VictoryBar
      style={barStyle}
      data={normalizedData}
      horizontal
      barWidth={({ index }) => index * 20 + 10}
    />
  </Chart>
```

This renders the Y axis on the bottom of the graph. I need to include another widget directly beneath the graph so I want the Y axis on the top, but I'm not sure if VictoryBar has the support for this. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you are talking about X-axis. Can you share a picture?

Comment: You can check in the document [VictoryAxis - orientation](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-axis#orientation), this property specify the position ex: `top` | `bottom` ...